# Relighting Workflow

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, normals

I always use following setup for relighting an object in compositing:

[image]

In most cases this works, but sometimes it's hard to adjust the direction of the light. Especially in terms accuracy it would be useful to **adjust real values instead of rotating the light direction ball**:

[image]

Is there more accurate way to adjust the values of the `normal pass`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to enable the [Amaranth plugin](http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth/) by Pablo Vazquez (not included with blender by default). This addon adds many features to blender including the ability to edit the individual values of the normal node:

[image]

While the changes aren't visible in the node itself, when the node is selected extra options appear in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) in the node editor.